# How to I change line color after calling matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code, take from thetechrepo tutorial, will plot some data with different colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()

#create data
x_series = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y_series_1 = [x**2 for x in x_series]
y_series_2 = [x**3 for x in x_series]

plt.plot(x_series, y_series_1, 'r-')
plt.plot(x_series, y_series_2, 'c--')
plt.show()
```

However what if I wanted to change the colors *after* I've called plot? For example how would I change the color of `series_1` to green after I had called `plt.plot(x_series, y_series_1, 'r-')`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use `set_color` on the `Line2D` object created by `plt.plot`. For example:

```
l1, = plt.plot(x_series, y_series_1, 'r-')
l2, = plt.plot(x_series, y_series_2, 'c--')

# Some time later...
l1.set_color('b')
l2.set_color('g')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding for completeness.  If you plot several line2Ds in one plot statement (eg when plotting a pandas df), the plot function will return a list/array of the line2D objects.